# SpringMvc - javax.validation.ValidationException

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using Spring 3.0. I am not using hibernate or maven dependencies. I have downloaded the jar files and added it to my classpath. I am receiving a javax.validation.ValidationException. After researching this issue i have included hibernate-core-3.5.6.jar and slf4-api.1.4.3.jar files to the classpath.

**Error Log**

```
2073 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include the [hibernate-validator library jar](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator/download).

[Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator) (version 4.x and above) is the reference implementation of `javax.validation.constraints`, also known as JSR-303 annotations.
Despite the name, this library has nothing to do with databases and relational mapping, it just does validation.

Comment: i did include the hibernate-validator.jar but i am still getting the following error :org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider. Do i need to specify any beans in the applicationContext.xml?

Comment: @dev_darin which verison of hibernate-validator are you using ?

Comment: i am now checking that and i am seeing 3.0 i would need to use 4.0 and earlier?

Comment: now getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, guess i need the slf4j.jar any suggestions on the version

Comment: @dev_darin don't know, maybe try looking at the end of [this blog post (click here)](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/), there is a list of maven dependencies. You can see that they use sl4j 1.6.1, but it was in early 2011.

Answer (score 6):

Add hibernate-validator dependency which has implementation of JSR 303 (bean validation).

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem ... I had this , bu did not want to use validation :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added hibernate-validator as a dependency in pom.xml and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason, REMOVING this maven dependency did the trick:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above are working for you, there is a chance that you are not using Java 8 or it hasn't been properly installed in your system(give it a check by typing `java --version` (for mac) in the terminal or command prompt). It was so for me. I had to uninstall Java and reinstall Java 8 (Go to this [correct way to uninstall java on mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324792/how-to-remove-java-10-or-revert-to-the-previous-version?newreg=2e37a0f9b8704f2aa4998510f9dd6629) if you are a mac user) and the problem was solved.